# Issue in building the "Dart SDK" on a linux armhf machine

Tags: dart

Has someone compiled "Dart SDK" for linux armhf ?
I have tried to build it from within a Raspberry but whit no success.
thanks in advance.
Giovanni.

Answer (score 0):

ARM support for Dart VM is a work in progress. You can contact vm-dev@dartlang.org to inquire about the ARM port status.